# Linux program used to gather installed packages, processes, listening ports, etc.?

Tags: linux, process, json, statistics, yaml

It's hard to Google this because it seems like everyone and their kid sister has written a script to gather system stats!

I once saw a mature program written that is used to gather system stats like installed packages, listening ports, users, partition information, etc. and dumped everything into one nice YAML (or was it JSON?). I was really impressed by how comprehensive it is.

I forgot what it was called, and now I have a need for it. Can you think of any mature programs available that does this? I'm not looking for a monitoring system or leveraging Facter; I just need a report of a current system as whole-circle as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly confident this will be closed as off-topic (product recommendation) soon, but the only "mature" program I've seen that does this type of thing is the `sosreport` (formerly `sysreport`) package/script in RHEL / Fedora.

Comment: I distinctly remember that this was an open-source program with a decent-looking website and the like.  I don't know if you'd call that a "product;" I'm not looking for any proprietary software to do this.

Comment: Sysreport doesn't have a web interface, but it's sure not proprietary. It's as open source as open source gets.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure If this is what you had in mind... But Nessus will do most, if not all, of that.

> http://www.tenable.com/products/nessus

Comment: It was an open-source program.

Comment: ah, yeah, that is the only one that I could think of, but if nessus won't do what you need it to, then I guess that is all I've got. Wouldn't be too difficult to write a bash script that would do what you need it too though.